# How to let page full load when use python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to parse date in page https://m.ctrip.com/webapp/vacations/tour/detail?productid=35940820,

[image],

but when I use python selenium to get this page, the part of contents not loaded, what can I do?

```
driver.get(real_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30, until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="_1wqbaeb10 _1wqbaeb6 _1wqbaeb6s"]')))
element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="_1wqbaeb10 _1wqbaeb6 _1wqbaeb6s"]')
```